# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I have a tsx file where the code is like below:

```
interface CommandProps {
    otherStuff: string;
    commandContainerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement | undefined>;
}

const getComponentProps = (): CommandProps => {
    return {
        otherStuff: 'stuff',
        commandContainerRef: undefined,
    };
};

.....
```

It gave me the error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement |
> undefined>'.

Then, I tired commandContainerRef: React.useRef(null), the above error is gone, but it gave me the eslint error below:

> Error - React Hook "React.useRef" is called in function
> "getComponentProps" that is neither a React function component nor a
> custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an
> uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
> (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

I am wondering how to address this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit the post to include a more complete and comprehensive code example that includes creating and using a React ref? [mcve] Are you trying to say that `commandContainerRef` is optional, or that it isn't but the ref's value can be undefined?

Comment: You shouldn't be passing refs via props. For that you want to use a `forwardRef`

Comment: @Phil It's perfectly valid to pass a React ref as a normal prop. There's nothing against it. Refs only need to be forwarded specifically when using the *special* `ref` prop on a React function component.

Comment: @DrewReese oops, I got it backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.RefObject<T>` is an interface with a read-only property named `current` of the given type `T` (or `null`), in this case `CommandProps` or `undefined` (or `null`).

So, if you want `commandContainerRef` returned from `getComponentProps` to be a `React.RefObject` to `undefined` this should work:

```
const getComponentProps = (): CommandProps => {
    return {
        otherStuff: 'stuff',
        commandContainerRef: { current: undefined },
    };
};
```

Or, depending on what your precise need is, you could alternatively change `commandContainerRef` to:

```
commandContainerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | undefined;
```

Then the `getComponentProps` implementation in the question should work.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I also tried commandContainerRef: React.createRef(), It works as well, so I think React.createRef() will generate undefined/null by default? Anyway, it's great it's working.